# Как поменять int на char?

Tags: java, unicode, char

Есть значения `int` от `1` до `8`. Я хочу, что бы в соответствии со значением выводился символ `char` от `a` до `h`.  У каждого символа есть свой номер. Допустим номер `а` - `3456`. Получается, чтобы вывести `а`, я должен вывести символ под номером `3455+1`, чтобы вывести `b`, я должен вывести `3455+2`, и т.п.

У меня несколько вопросов:

1. Можно так сделать?
2. Какой номер у `a`?
3. Как вывести символ по его номеру?

Comment: [какой номер у a](https://unicode-table.com/ru/0061/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можно.
2. В кодировке ASCII `a` имеет `97` номер.
3. `System.out.println((char)65);` будет `А`

   `System.out.println( (int)'A' );` будет `65`.

Comment: @andreymal , совершено верно, я совершил опечатку.

Answer (score 2):

Java позволяет сделать это достаточно просто:

```
    // вывести нормер символа, если мы знаем символ
    System.out.println((int)Character.valueOf('a')); // 97
    // вывести инфрмацию о символе по номеру
    System.out.println(Character.getName(97)); // LATIN SMALL LETTER A
    // вывести символ по номеру
    System.out.println((char)97); // a

    // решить задачу из требований
    int i = 2;
    System.out.println((char)(i + 96)); // b
```

Answer (score 0):

Вывести символы от 'a' до 'h':

```
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'h'; ch++) 
    System.out.println(ch);
```